# Display SQL table data on website

Tags: php, mysql

So I thought I had this down and it made sure to let me know that I've screwed up again.

```
<?php
        $username="root";
        $password="**********";
        $database="website";
        $server="localhost";
        $connect=mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
        ;
        @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
        mysql_select_db($database, $connect) or die ("Error selecting specified database on this server: ".mysql_error());
        $cdquery="SELECT content FROM homepage";
        $cdresult=mysql_query($cdquery) or die ("Query to get data from the first table failed: ".mysql_error());
        echo "<p>$cdresult</p>";

        mysql_close();
        ?>
```

Is what I currently have for my code to display my information from my table website and from the column data. I'm not sure what Resource id #4 is, but it's displaying itself instead of the content. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong so that it doesn't display the information that I have in content?

Comment: Could you actually show the error that you are getting? There isn't any reference to ResourceID4 in your code at all.

Comment: I never referenced resource I'd 4. It is displayed where I expected my SQL data to show.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch the results from the result resource [via `mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). The query, on success, returns a result resource, which is used by the database connection to spool results back. It contains no row data on its own until rows are fetched:

```
$cdresult = mysql_query($cdquery) or die ("Query to get data from the first table failed: ".mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($cdresult)) {
  // The column is an array key in $row
  // Wrapped in htmlspecialchars() to escape for HTML output
  echo "<p>" . htmlspecialchars($row['cdresult']) . "</p>";
}
```

The old `mysql_*()` functions have begun the deprecation process, and will eventually be removed from PHP.  It is recommended that you spend some time learning one of the more modern APIs supporting prepared statements, such as MySQLi or PDO instead of investing too much time learning the `mysql_*()` functions.

A couple more tips:

You have two calls to `mysql_select_db()`.  You only need one of them.  Avoid using the `@` error suppression operator, since it hides error information you need to be able to see while developing your code.

```
// Don't do this. Just do the next one
// @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
mysql_select_db($database, $connect) or die ("Error selecting specified database on this server: ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: should be `$row[0]` in your `echo`